# HTML Data not load in UIWebview when passCode screen is present

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, locking

let me explain step by step:

1. Step 1 - in my app Fist of all listing screen.
2. Step 2 - press on any no of list, it will come detail screen and
   call web service and fetch data.
3. Step 3 - fetch data like many types of HTML data so in my detail
   screen i am using 4 UiWebView for Dynamic UiWebview in scroll.
4. step-4 in my app Passcode Functionality is there (And it's On).

If i am press on listing screen and it will call detail screen for particular list data load, and i am waiting till all UiWebview Load, the Passcode functionality is work properly.

What is problem let me explain in detail.

if we are just coming Detail screen and web service call and immediately press home button, now i am again launch the app and passcode screen present, After Enter my pass code succesfully i am coming in Detail screen, BUT what i see all UiWebview is not Loaded, even i have all data store in my model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing silly mistake over here in HTML String :) .

```
NSString *html5 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body style=\"background:#ffffff;\"><div style = \"font:16px;margin-top:0px;\" ><object width=\"245\" height=\"0\">%@</object></div></body></html>",objDetail.str_DealName];
```

Simply i am remove ViewPort and set font size in style.